# Many QPushButtons clicked connecting using exec()

Tags: python, pyqt5, exec, qpushbutton

I have write this code:

```py
    def top_music_clips(self,clips):
        try:
            self.top_20_clips = clips
            counter = 0
            for clip in self.top_20_clips:
                counter += 1
                exec("self.main_self.ui.music_clip_"+str(counter)+".clicked.connect(lambda state,clip_id="+str(clip["id"])+":self.top_clip_clicked(clip_id))")
                exec("self.main_self.ui.music_clip_"+str(counter)+".setText('"+str(clip["title"])+"')")
                exec("self.main_self.ui.music_clip_"+str(counter)+".setStyleSheet('QPushButton{font-size:7px;}')")
            #example for music_clip_1
            #self.main_self.ui.music_clip_1.clicked.connect(lambda state,clip_id=self.top_20_clips[0]["id"]:self.top_clip_clicked(clip_id))
        except:
            error_message = traceback.format_exc()
            self.main_self.open_music_clip_deck_error_window(error_message)
```

But when i push the button the program crashes. Note that the code in the comment work!

What's going wrong?

Comment: Don't use `exec()` (or `eval()`) for this, **ever**. Use [`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) and create local functions in the for loop.

Comment: @musicamante can you explain better: you don't mean: `print(getattr(eval("self.main_self.ui.music_clip_"+str(counter)), 'objectName')())`

Comment: The problem is in the lambda expression. When i use: `self.top_clip_clicked` there is no error but i want to know this argument.

Comment: I've already said to ***NOT*** use either `exec()` or `eval()`. The problem is not just the lambda expression, but the fact that you're using the `exec()` for the wrong reason. Have you read the documentation of `getattr()` linked above? Do you understand its usage and purpose? Just use that to get the target object and then work with it. For instance: `btn = getattr(self.main_self.ui, 'music_clip_{}'.format(counter))`, then you can access the button members using `btn`, including its signals: `btn.clicked.connect(lambda state, clip_id=str(clip["id"]): self.top_clip_clicked(clip_id))`.

Comment: Ok now works. I will also change and for the other two `exec()`. Thanks